# View Microsoft Office files in the browser

Tags: javascript, php, ms-office

I have been wondering for a while if there is a way to view (lets's say a *.pptx) file in a browser. Imagine  Dropbox's feature. I'm making a Content Sharing System and it would be wonderful if a user could see his *.docx or *.pptx or whatever microsoft office file. I found [this](http://www.aspose.com/cloud/powerpoint-api.aspx) but it is paid.

Comment: Did you take a look at https://github.com/PHPOffice?

Answer (score -2):

Try out OneDrive.com or OneDrive for Business within Office 365. There you can view and edit files online. You can also use SharePoint to display files online.

If you want to embed the doc in your own website, try this Project on github, https://github.com/officedev/pnp-wopi.

HTH-Oliver

Comment: Why did you downgrade my answer, is this Project to complicated ? did it not solve your Problem?